# Fastest dummy variable conversion package / function

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, xgboost, dummy-variable

I have a data frame with a bunch of factor variables that need to get converted to dummy variables for use with the `xgboost` package.  I'm currently using the `dummyVars` function in `caret` which is pretty good but kind of slow.  Is there a faster way to do this conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `Matrix` package, `model.matrix` and `sparse.model.matrix` both do the job and I have always found them quite fast. e.g.

```
require(Matrix)
oat_data <- data.frame(  num = c(1,2,4,8,16), 
                      animal = c("cat","cat","dog","cat","horse"), 
                        oats = c("likes","dislikes","dislikes","likes","dislikes"))

dense_mat <- model.matrix(~.-1,data=oat_data, verbose = F)
sparse_mat <- sparse.model.matrix(~.-1,data=oat_data, verbose = F)

dense_mat
  num animalcat animaldog animalhorse oatslikes
1   1         1         0           0         1
2   2         1         0           0         0
3   4         0         1           0         0
4   8         1         0           0         1
5  16         0         0           1         0

sparse_mat
  num animalcat animaldog animalhorse oatslikes
1   1         1         .           .         1
2   2         1         .           .         .
3   4         .         1           .         .
4   8         1         .           .         1
5  16         .         .           1         .
```

Very fast even with hundreds of variables that have many factors.